# Sorting stability not maintained when zipping

Tags: python

[image]

Code here:

```
nums = ['12', '02', '4', '023', '65', '83', '224', '50']
sortt = [10, 60, 2, 605, 49, 35, 2, 96]

new_nums = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(sortt, nums))]
print(new_nums)
```

It seems that sorted is not maintaining sorting stability here even though it is supposed to. Can anyone explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "stability" here? What were you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would have been nice if you told us the expected result.

It would be also appreciated if you didn't post a screen shot, but something that allows us to copy paste your code snippet.

I guess you mean, that '4' should be before '224'.

This is not how sorting stability works.

The tuple (2, '224') is smaller than (2, '4') and is therefore sorted first

With your code you did not have two identical results. With an explicit key function that just uses the first value of the item to sort you should get it.

However I did not test as I didn't want to retype the code from your screen shot, So I hope I didn't make any typos.

Just try

```
new_nums = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(sortt, nums), key=lambda v: v[0])]
```

and you should get the sort stability

Sort stability means, if a sort finds identical values (identical sort keys), that it will then preserve the previously existing order

Answer (score 0):

That's correct:

If you print

```
print([v for v in sorted(zip(sortt,nums))])
```

you'll get:

```
[(2, '4'), (2, '224'), (10, '12'), (35, '83'), (49, '65'), (60, '02'), (96, '50'), (605, '023')]
```

If you want a stability sort, you need to sort on the first key of the tuples, which is numeric:

```
print([v for v in sorted(zip(sortt,nums), key=lambda x:x[0])])
# [(2, '224'), (2, '4'), (10, '12'), (35, '83'), (49, '65'), (60, '02'), (96, '50'), (605, '023')]
```

Comment: Ideally I would want the '4' before the '224'. Is there any way to do that

Comment: `key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1], 10))`, to ensure that the strings are actually sorted by the integer they represent (assuming these should all be treated as base-10 values).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is behaving in its correct way because

`zip(sortt, nums)` is

```
[(10, '12'), (60, '02'), (2, '4'), (605, '023'), (49, '65'), (35, '83'), (2, '224'), (96, '50')]
```

If you sort it, it looks like below -

```
[(2, '224'), (2, '4'), (10, '12'), (35, '83'), (49, '65'), (60, '02'), (96, '50'), (605, '023')]
```

If you sort a list of tuple, it sort at first by the first element, That is why you are seeing the first elements of the tuple in the sorted array sorted. But if first element of two tuple is same then it sorts it by the second element. Here for example is the sorted array you can see that `(2, '224')`, `(2, '4')` has same first element, so they are sorted by the second element. As `'224'` is alphabetically smaller than `'4'`, the tuple containing it will come earlier in the sorted list.

And if the tuple had more elements and even the second elements were same as well, then it will sort by the third element and so on.